# Wait when open app after push notification

Tags: objective-c

When user get a notification when the app is in background , than he push the notification message in home screen , than when the app is open this one is being called :

```
//on delegate class
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
```

Than here, i want to perform something , than wait for his delegate here, only than to let the app become active again, how can i eliminate the app from starting, only when i am ready for it ?

Comment: I think you can´t because when you open a push notification, it´s like open an app wheb tap in the icon of your app but you are opening your app with values from your push notification. Maybe you could use a loading screen while you do your previous work before to use the information of your push notification

Comment: ok got it , thanks a lot . i will manage it in another place..